Power of Toffoli vs T in quantum logic
In the broader scope of quantum compilation of relevant algorithms, how would one assess the power of Clifford+T versus Clifford+Toffoli computation models? Previous work has shown that the size of the set of exactly implementable unitaries under Clifford+T is larger than Clifford+Toffoli, but (1) not all of these unitaries are "useful" and (2) exactly implementable is not necessarily what we care about. Thus, this question is somewhat subjective. However, are algorithms of interest in the absence of the QEC model usually written in terms of T gates or Toffolis?

I think of the gatesets as equivalent. Clifford+Toffoli can do everything Clifford+T can do, if given access to a single $|T\rangle$ state. Clifford+Toffoli can duplicate the T state, allowing an unlimited number of T gates to be done by gate teleportation.

So there's a certain sense in which the differences between the two gate sets is very unstable. Without a T state, Clifford+Toffoli can't make a T state. But with one, it can make many.
This is relevant in contexts where making a T state would be expensive, but you have access to cheap Toffolis, meaning you only have to make one expensive state then can just start duplicating it. Like if you had an error correcting code with transversal Toffolis, but no support for the T gate. You just have to bootstrap one T state by expensive distillation, then you can forget the limitation.
